# ggplot in R - stacked bar not plotting correct value

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I am new to R programming and thus request help from all experts in here. 
Please refer to the code below where I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart.

```
g <- ggplot(df7, aes(Country))
g + geom_bar(aes(fill=Type, text=paste("Year: ", StartYear)), width = 0.75) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.6)) +
labs(title="Visit Activities by Country", subtitle="Displayed by Country")
```

The data frame df7 has 64 rows, with the value of column 'n' which is a grouped count being 1 for rows 1 to 55 and the rest are in the image below.

**rows and columns in data frame df7**

[image]

Problem: value of 'n' in rows 63 and 64 are 4 and 9 respectively. But the stacked bar chart is showing these as 1 and 1 only. Please see the chart image below with black circle highlighted bars.

**the actual bar graph generated by the code**

[image]

Please help in identify why the last 2 rows of the data frame is getting truncated while plotting the stacked bar chart.

Comment: Your code doesn't mention the `n` column, so ggplot doesn't use the `n` column. `ggplot` is just doing it's default of row counts. If you want `ggplot` to use the `n` column in the plot, then you need to map that column inside `aes()`. Try adding `y = n` inside `aes()`, and switching from `geom_bar` to `geom_col`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gregor. Your solution worked. I understood my gap in not plotting n column to specifically indicate the count.